# What does ~ mean with regards to semver in bower/npm?

Tags: npm, bower

If I do `bower install` or `npm install` it adds a `~` prefix to the version installed, what does that accomplish over just specifying the version number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And 5 seconds later I found the answer at the [npm docs](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/misc/semver.html):

> ~1.2 := >=1.2.0-0 <1.3.0-0 "Any version starting with 1.2"

Comment: Welp since this was the first response from Google saved me digging around NPM docs. thanks

Answer (score 0):

These are all the same and can be used interchangeably... any version starting with '1.2'

```
~1.2 or 1.2.x or 1.2.*
```